# Why can I not import Caffe in PyCharm but can import it in terminal?

Tags: python, pycharm, caffe

I want to import Caffe. I can import it in terminal but not in PyCharm.

I have tried some suggestions like adding `include /usr/local/cuda-7.0/lib64` to `/user/etc/ld.so.conf` file but still it can not import this module. However, I think this is not a good solution as I am using the CPU mode only.

[image]

I am using Linux Mint.

The output for `sys.path` in PyCharm terminal is:

```py
>>> sys.path
['', 
'/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python27.zip', 
'/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7', 
'/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', 
'/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', 
'/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-old', 
'/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', 
'/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages', 
'/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Sphinx-1.4.1-y2.7.egg',
'/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-23.0.0-py2.7.egg']
>>>
```

and when I run `sys.path` in PyCharm itself, I get:

```py
['/opt/pycharm-community-2016.2.3/helpers/pydev',
'/home/user/',
'/opt/pycharm-community-2016.2.3/helpers/pydev',
'/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python27.zip',
'/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7',
'/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
'/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
'/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
'/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
'/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
'/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Sphinx-1.4.1-py2.7.egg',
'/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-23.0.0-py2.7.egg',
'/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions',
'/home/user/']
```

which is not exactly the same as the time I ran it in terminal.

moreover, as I run the `import caffe` in PyCharm the error is as bellow:

```
/home/user/anaconda2/bin/python /home/user/important_commands.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/important_commands.py", line 11, in <module>
    import caffe
ImportError: No module named caffe

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Did you select the correct interpreter?

Comment: @ Giordano yes my default pycharm interpreter is `~/anaconda2/bin/python`

Comment: Is editor just not detecting module or is ImportError raised when you attempt to run the code via Pycharm? Also, what paths does sys.path return in terminal/Pycharm?

Comment: Please [edit] the post. Comments aren't meant for code

Comment: Does this match sys.path you get from running a file using Pycharm?

Comment: @Mirac7 : can you please tell me what I should do with that difference?

Comment: Everything importable should be in sys.path, and since Pycharm contains all paths you should be able to import. This is unlikely solution, but try to clear caches and restart Pycharm [as described here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.2/cleaning-system-cache.html)

Comment: @Mirac7  I did it too but still I have the error!:(

Comment: I'm not sure what is causing your issue, but you may try [(re)installing caffe again via Pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html).

Answer (score 4):

This solution worked for me. I think that the problem is that pycharm doesn´t charge the libraries from the bashrc.

1. Open Pycharm
2. Go to File --> settings --> project interpreter

[image]

3. Open the bar with all the possible interpreters and press show all.

[image]

4. Click the last button of the options (Brown bottom).
5. Add the python path (/home/user/caffe/python)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I installed caffe using pycharm terminal too but it did not work. Finally I added `sys.path.extend([/home/user/caffe-master/python])` to python consule and meanwhile I wrote the following in my code.

```
 import sys
 sys.path.append("/home/user/caffe-master/python/")
 import caffe
```

and it worked!!!

Answer (score 3):

You need to add this same path under you interpreters path.
Settings -> Project interpreter ->click the cogwheel next to interpreter -> More -> click on icon that says 'Show paths for interpreter' -> add path -> Chaos Solved.

Comment: this didn't work for me. I tried adding `path/to/caffe/python/` and also `path/to/caffe/python/caffe`. In the former I couldn't import caffe, in the second, my python console couldn't connect and I couldn't import caffe. What exactly did you add to the interpreter paths?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding caffe in the project interpreter. Just use the + on the right side for the list of available packages. Search for caffe and click on Install Package.